# cache with least accessed items eviction

Tags: python, cache

I wrote this code, in order to implement a cache decorator which handles **least accessed eviction**.

The role of this decorator is to **memoize** decorated functions calls with args and kwargs and return the previously computed value if still in cache.

Warning, this handles only serializable args and kwargs, for the sake of simplicity.

Please review it and tell me if this makes sense.

## The code:

```
import json
import hashlib
from collections import OrderedDict


class EvictionCache(OrderedDict):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        max_size = kwargs.pop('max_size', None)
        super(EvictionCache, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self._max_size = max_size

    @property
    def full(self):
        return len(self) >= self._max_size

    def set(self, hash, value):
        if self.full:
            self.evict()
        super(EvictionCache, self).__setitem__(hash, value)

    def get(self, hash):
        value = super(EvictionCache, self).pop(hash, None)
        if value:
            super(EvictionCache, self).__setitem__(hash, value)
        return value

    def evict(self):
        print 'evicting oldest cached item'
        super(EvictionCache, self).popitem(last=False)


def cache(max_size=None):

    def make_md5(args, kwargs):
        data = dict(args=args, kwargs=kwargs)
        md5 = hashlib.md5(json.dumps(data, sort_keys=True)).hexdigest()
        return md5

    def wrapper(f):
        # make this cache belong to the decorated function to prevent the cache
        # to be shared between different decorated functions
        f._cache = EvictionCache(max_size=max_size)

        def inner(*args, **kwargs):
            md5 = make_md5(args, kwargs)
            res = f._cache.get(md5)
            if res:
                print 'from cache'
                return res

            res = f(*args, **kwargs)
            print 'to cache'
            f._cache.set(md5, res)

            return res

        return inner
    return wrapper


@cache(max_size=2)
def func(x):
    return x * 2


if __name__ == '__main__':

    print func(1)
    print func(2)
    print func(2)
    print func(1)
    print func(2)
    print func(3)
    print func(4)
    print func(5)
```

## output

```
to cache
2
to cache
4
from cache
4
from cache
2
from cache
4
to cache
evicting oldest cached item
6
to cache
evicting oldest cached item
8
to cache
evicting oldest cached item
10
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't really feel subclassing a built-in data structure and defining your custom `get()` and `set()` methods is a good idea. One of the downsides of the current implementation is that if I would do `self.cache[key] = value` - this will not go through the cache's `set()` method and, hence, will not go through the "eviction" check at all. If you are subclassing a dictionary or an ordered dictionary, [properly define the `__getitem__()` and `__setitem__()` magic methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2390827/how-to-properly-subclass-dict-and-override-getitem-setitem) instead of writing your custom `get()` and `set()` on top of it.

Also check [this implementation](https://github.com/stucchio/Python-LRU-cache/blob/master/lru/__init__.py#L201) that has a simpler wrapper, but uses a "proxy" "cached function" helper class.

And, here is the source code of the [Python's `functools.lru_cache`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/functools.py#L448) for the reference.

Some other minor notes:

- use `print()` as a *function* for Python-3.x compatibility

Comment: Thanks, I agree with your points, but, in my defense, this subclass is only meant to be used by the decorator and only this way. I had initially defined custom __getitem__ and __setitem__ but refactored them to get / set, to match most existing caches implementations. I'll definitely have a look at what you shared. Thanks again!

Comment: @Apero sure, you have valid reasons. I'd then may be would not subclass `OrderedDict` and have an ordered dict as an internal attribute of a regular `EvictionCache` class inherited from `object`. Would probably be a bit cleaner. You've probably noticed I've tried to come up with something cleaner for the "cached function" part, but decided to remove it from the answer - was not sure if my version was better. I'm also not sure about the need to use md5 and json dump..probably having `repr((args, kwargs))` as a key would be good enough, what do you think?..Thanks.

Comment: Damn it, I didn't even know functools had and lru cache implementation. I just started coding my own. Also, yes, the internal attribute instead of sublcassing would be cleaner. Great review!

Comment: The boltons distribution's `cacheutils` module also had an LRU class, along with several decorators for caching, in case the funcutils implementation doesn't do everything you want.